# Ruby Rest-client keeps correcting the uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest-client

I'm using rest-client to make a post request to a certain address. Unfortunately rest-client keeps correcting the web adres from 'https' to 'http'. Which then gives back an error.

I already looked at the documentation whether this maybe was a setting for the gem. Anyone knows how I can 'force' rest-client to access the desired address.

Thx in advance!

used code is:

```
  uri = 'https://sandbox.api.online.unit4.nl/V19/OAuth/Token'

  payload = {
    code: params[:code],
    client_id: '#{@client_id}',
    client_secret: '#{@client_secret}',
    redirect_uri: '#{@client_redirect_url}',
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
  }

  response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, url: uri,      headers: {params: payload})
```

curl:

```
> GET /V19/OAuth/Token HTTP/1.1
> Host: sandbox.api.online.unit4.nl
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< content-length: 27
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< date: Wed, 06 Dec 2017 15:21:44 GMT
< p3p: CP="NON CUR OTPi OUR NOR UNI"
< server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
< x-aspnetmvc-version: 5.2
< cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< x-powered-by: ASP.NET
< x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
< pragma: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: PD_STATEFUL_88eb7504-dfe9-11e2-8624-005056af4a32=sandbox.api.online.unit4.nl; Path=/
< Set-Cookie: LB_online_unit4=1493375404.20480.0000; path=/
```

Comment: Could you past the code you're using? Also, are you sure there're no redirects? What does `curl -v YOUR_HTTPS_ADDRESS` return?

Answer (score 1):

Could be that your variables aren't getting [interpolated](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+string+interpolation&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS694US695&oq=ruby+string+int&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.2358j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). With single quotes `'#{@variable}'` doesn't work. Try switching the single quotes to double quotes (`'' => ""`). What is happening is that instead of sending the actual client id and secret, you are sending the string `#{@client_id}`.

Try

```
uri = 'https://sandbox.api.online.unit4.nl/V19/OAuth/Token'

  payload = {
    code: params[:code],
    client_id: @client_id,
    client_secret: @client_secret,
    redirect_uri: @client_redirect_url,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
  }

  response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, url: uri, headers: {params: payload})
```

Comment: I tried that, but the values didn't appear in the query string then, only the keys did. So I switched the double quotes to single quotes which solved the problem. Could try again though, maybe I overlooked something.